# What part of meat is mince meat made from?

Tags: meat

It seems to me mince meat contains connective tissue(i.e white bits) and a lot of fat also comes from it.  Therefore I imagine it is not a lean cut of meat.

What part of meat does mince meat usually come from?

Comment: Every single of your questions amazes and confuses me at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean homemade mince, from a high end butcher, cheapest supermarket options? There is not necessarily a "to be ground up" cut of an animal.

Comment: Are you asking about mincemeat or minced meat?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to ground beef (as we call it in america) then it can be from anything really. Usually trimmings. Ground beef for hamburgers is usually from the chuck, but sirloin is also used (among every other cut of beef in theory)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionaly, Mincemeat is made with [Suet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suet), maybe this is what you are feeling in your Mincemeat.

It has a different kind of texture than other kind of fat (in my experience)

A quick look at different recipes shows that most of them do not add meat to the Mincemeat and when the meat is added, it only says beef, no specific parts are listed.

Comment: Note that [mincemeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mincemeat) ≠ [mince / minced meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_meat).